# Exception : using inner joins in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a sql query like below,

```
SELECT patient.*,
contact.telephone
from patient
INNER JOIN contact ON patient.`idPatient` = contact.`idPatient`
```

These are my works,

**Patient.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 8, 2016 1:55:08 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="db.Patient" table="patient" catalog="example_hibernate" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idPatient" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idPatient" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="title" type="string">
            <column name="title" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="firstName" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string">
            <column name="lastName" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="middleName" type="string">
            <column name="middleName" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="dob" type="date">
            <column name="dob" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="martitalStatus" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="martitalStatus" />
        </property>
        <property name="gender" type="string">
            <column name="gender" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="nic" type="string">
            <column name="nic" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateCreated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="dateCreated" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastUpdated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="lastUpdated" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="contacts" table="contact" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="idPatient" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="db.Contact" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Contact.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 8, 2016 1:55:08 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="db.Contact" table="contact" catalog="example_hibernate" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idContact" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idContact" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="patient" class="db.Patient" fetch="select">
            <column name="idPatient" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="telephone" type="string">
            <column name="telephone" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="address" type="string">
            <column name="address" length="45" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then I used above sql like below,

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new HibernateUtil().getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        List<Object[]> africanContinents = session.createQuery(
                "SELECT patient.*,\n"
                + "contact.telephone\n"
                + "from patient\n"
                + "INNER JOIN contact ON patient.`idPatient` = contact.`idPatient`")
                .list();
HibernateUtil.shutdown();
```

But this bought me following exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '`' [SELECT patient.*,
contact.telephone
from patient
INNER JOIN contact ON patient.`idPatient` = contact.`idPatient`]
```

I have no idea about how to handle this exception . Because this sql query is correct. 
Have any ideas about this exception ?

Answer (score 1):

The query in createQuery should be written in HQL or JPQL.

So you could rewrite your query in HQL (something 'like select p,c.telephone from patient inner join contact') see documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/chapters/query/hql/HQL.html)

Or you could use your SQL query by calling session.createSQLQuery instead of session.createQuery

Hope this helps.
Sebastien